# Restler returns 404 when index is outside restler dir

Tags: php, routes, restler

so i get the following error

```
{
"error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found"
},
"debug": {
    "source": "Routes.php:354 at route stage",
    "stages": {
        "success": [
            "get"
        ],
        "failure": [
            "route",
            "negotiate",
            "message"
        ]
    }
}
```

my project folder is

```
xampp
->htdocs
-->soa_lab2
--->Restler-master
--->index.php
--->WeatherReport.php
--->dbAccess.php
--->.htaccess
```

however, looks like the htaccess is not working

this is my index.php

```
    <?php
    require_once 'Restler-master/vendor/restler.php';
    use Luracast\Restler\Restler;

    $r = new Restler();
    $r->addAPIClass('WeatherReport');
    $r->handle();
```

I use the standart .htaccess from restler examples

what should i do?
Please help.. Thank you

Comment: Use an application template from https://github.com/Luracast/Restler-Application instead

Comment: But, i don't use laravel.. are there other options? changing the htaccess maybe? since it turned out that i can't open the examples too, with the same error @Luracast

Comment: above repository has few templates, one that uses laravel components is one of them. For a simpler template see https://github.com/Luracast/Restler-Application/tree/basic